# Clarification for the usage of 'should' in this sentence

Tags: grammar

The phrase comes from a song named Black Oak by Slaughter Beach Dog.

"Magnetic letters neat, and now arranged in such a way that they should spell his lover's name."

I'm curious about the usage of the word 'should' in this context. It seems like an odd word choice in this context. Can someone share some examples of similar phrases? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like an everyday use of the word *should* to me. Can you explain what you think is unique about the construction of the sentence or the word itself?

Comment: @JasonBassford I think the OP means that it is not used in the sense of "obligation", or advice.

Comment: @Cascabel But the dictionary definition of the word isn't restricted to that sense in the first place. So, there's nothing *special* about its use here. (And, again, I'm not sure what's meant by the "name for this kind of usage.")

Comment: The cited context is one where ***should*** is just the past tense of ***shall*** (in the sense of ***will***). It could reasonably be discarded completely, or replaced by ***do*** or ***did***. Or replaced by Simple Past with no auxiliary, as *...in such a way that they **spelled / spelt** his lover's name.* Compare *It's funny [that] you [**should**] say that (...you **said** that)*.

Comment: FF is right (as usual). In normal usage, "should" should be deleted from the sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This answers my question. Apologies to others if my question seemed unclear or poorly worded. I just thought the use of should in this context seemed like an odd word choice and so I wanted clarification on the grammatical aspect of it's usage. Thank you!

Comment: Let's not forget that poetry and lyrics do whatever they need to do.